# What does the regular expression \|(?=\w=>) mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am an amateur in JavaScript. [I saw this other (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757049/use-split-for-splitting-a-string), and it made me wonder. Can you tell me what does the below regular expression exactly mean?

```
split(/\|(?=\w=>)/)
```

Does it split the string with `|`?

Answer (score 7):

The regular expression is contained in the slashes.
It means

```
\|        # A pipe symbol. It needs to be scaped with a backslash
          # because otherwise it means "OR"
(?=       # a so-called lookahead group. It checks if its contents match 
          # at the current position without actually advancing in the string
   \w=>   # a word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) followed by =>
)         # end of lookahead group.
```

Answer (score 4):

It splits the string on `|` but only if its followed by a char in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `=>`

Example:

It will split `a|b=>` on the `|`

It will not split `a|b` on the `|`

Answer (score 2):

It splits the string on every '|' followed by (?) an alphanumerical character (\w, shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_]) + the character sequence '=>'.

[Here's a link that can help you understand regular expressions in javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Breakdown of the regular expression:

- `/` regular expression literal start delimiter
- `\|` match `|` in the string, `|` is a special character in regex, so `\` is used to escape it
- `(?=` Is a lookahead expression, it checks to see if a string follows the expression without matching it
- `\w=>` matches any alphanumeric string (including `_`), followed by `=>`
- `)/` marks the end of the lookahead expression and the end of the regex

In short, the string will be split on `|` if it is followed by any alphanumeric character or underscore and then `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the pipe character is escaped so it's treated as a literal pipe. The split occurs on pipes that are followed by any alphanumeric and '=>'.

The '|' is also used in regular expressions as a sort of OR operator. For example:

```
split(/k|i|tt|y/)
```

Would split on either a 'k', an 'i', a 'tt' or a 'y' character.

Answer (score 0):

Trimming the delimiting characters, we get `\|(?=\w=>)`

- `|` is a special character in regex, so it should be escaped with a backslash as `\|`
- `(?=REGEX)` is syntax for positive look ahead: matches only if `REGEX` matches, but doesn't consume the substring that matches `REGEX`. The match to the `REGEX` doesn't become part of the matched result. Had it been mere `\|\w=>`, the parent string would be split around `|a=>` instead of `|`.

Thus `/\|(?=\w=>)/` matches only those `|` characters that are followed by `\w=>`. It matches `|a=>` but not `|a>`, `||` etc.

Consider the example string from the linked question: `a=>aa|b=>b||b|c=>cc`. If it wasn't for the lookahead, split will yield an array of `[a=>aa, b||b, cc]`. With lookahead, you'll get `[a=>aa, b=>b||b, c=>cc]`, which is the desired output.